# Is it possible to create a bookmark on the Google Docs API?

Tags: python, google-docs-api

Is it possible to create a bookmark in the Google Docs API for a specific paragraph element and then get the bookmarkId of the bookmark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately at the moment this isn't possible to do.*

#### Feature Request:

Google's Issue Tracker is a place for developers to report issues and make feature requests for their development services, and a Feature Request for this has already been made over there.

You can view this feature request [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135711136), to which you can click the star (☆) in the top left to let Google know more people want this feature to be implemented.